# How to return another return?

Tags: python, return

I'm looking to use functions within my Python program to make it cleaner and more efficient, Within my function I either return true or false depending on a user's selection. Though in the case they enter an incorrect / invalid response, I'd like to return a return that way asking more questions don't be asked.

**Edit:**

To be a bit more descriptive; I'd like to re-create this:

```
def askquestion(question):
    response = input(question, "Enter T or F")
    if response == "T":
        return True
    elif response == "F":
        return False
    else:
        return None 

def askmultiple():
    questionOne = askquestion("Do you fruits?")
    if questionOne == None:
        return # Exit the function, not asking more questions

    questionTwo = askquestion("Do you Apples?")
    if questionTwo == None:
        return # Exit the function, not asking more questions
```

I want to cut out checking afterwards if it is `None` and just return return.

Comment: Can you please show the code you have so far so we have an idea of what you are doing

Comment: "I'd like to return a return" this doesn't make sense. `return` is part of a statement, it is not an object, thus it cannot be returned. you might as well ask "how do I return an `if`"

Comment: This sounds like you want what [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/364696) was asking for. Only reason I'm not immediately marking it a duplicate is that your question is too vague to be sure it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't create a return statement at the end of a function that is equal to a sole `return` and those two are equal to `return None` call.

So you may organize your code like:

```
if returned_value is None:
    # do something a
elif returned_value is False:
    # do something else
else:  # value is True
    # do something b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a while loop to make sure that the user inputs a correct input.
For example:

```py
while not response.isdigit():
     response =  input("That was not a number try again")
```

In this case, while the user input, "response" is not a number the python console will keep asking for a response. For a basic template,

```py
while not (what you want):
    (ask for input again)
```

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use an exception flow.

```py
def ask_question(prompt):
    """Asks a question, translating 'T' to True and 'F' to False"""
    response = input(prompt)

    table = {'T': True, 'F': False}
    return table[response.upper()]  # this allows `t` and `f` as valid answers, too.

def ask_multiple():
    questions = [
        "Do you fruits?",
        "Do you apples?",
        # and etc....
    ]

    try:
        for prompt in questions:
            result = ask_question(prompt)
    except KeyError as e:
        pass  # this is what happens when the user enters an incorrect response
```

Since `table[response.upper()]` will raise a `KeyError` if `response.upper()` is neither `'T'` nor `'F'`, you can catch it down below and use that flow to move you out of the loop.

---

Another option is to write a validator that forces the user to answer correctly.

```
def ask_question(prompt):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt)
        if response.upper() in ['T', 'F']:
            break
    return True if response.upper() == 'T' else False
```

Comment: Did this work for you please checkmark it if it did. Thanks!